# Repair/Reset Hard Disk - don't mind losing data

Tags: hard-drive, raid, alienware

I have an Alienware M14x R2 with a Seagate Momentus hybrid HDD/SSD.

I clean installed Windows 10 today and I booted Gparted from a USB to edit my partitions. I accidentally ended up moving the OS partition. I am ashamed to say that I panicked and I disconnected the USB.

I was able to reinstall Windows 10, but it runs slow and it is unstable. My BIOS no longer recognises the RAID0 setup and says my 750GB HDD is non-Raid and my 32gb SSD is disabled.

I would like to format the hard disk and return it to factory settings, complete with RAID setup. I don't have any important data on the hard disk.

I am sure this question has been answered many times, but I cannot find it in the sea of questions about saving important data on the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it is a Dell model there should be instructions on the web somewhere... I did the following on my old Inspiron 17R Special to get it going after I revamped its hardware. In terms of release dates they are almost identical so the steps involved are most likely identical

[Intel Smart Response](http://www.pcworld.com/article/248828/how_to_setup_intel_smart_response_ssd_caching_technology.html)

[Setting the quick start.](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwjM1NTq8_rHAhUhJqYKHYgACgQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.intel.com%2Fsupport%2Fmotherboards%2Fdesktop%2Fsb%2Frapid_start_technology_user_guide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGw7Nj_6cbq5tJ0Gi0LmHsNTCF4XQ&cad=rja)

Comment: Thanks, Aedazan.

I was able to format the hard drive, do a clean install of Windows 10, reinstall the Intel Rapid Storage utility, "disassociate" and then "reassociate" my HDD and SSD. Now the SSD cache works again.